# Page images is not appearing in the pinit window in mobile view

Tags: jquery

After click on the pinit icon ,then pinit window opens but images are not shows inside it ... can anybody please recommend me that what is wrong in this code -

**pinit html code** -

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-538d454f05422818"></script>
```

**html structure appearing like** -

```
<div class="at3PinWinMn">
<span class="atNoImg" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">There are no valid images to share.</span>
</div>
```

**html structure should be appearing like -**

```
<div class="at3PinWinMn">
<span class="at3ImgSpanOuter addthis_32x32_style">
<span class="atImgSpanInner">
<img width="190" height="190" title="Smiley face" alt="Smiley face" src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/pinit_POC/img/1.jpeg" style="margin-top: -2.5px; margin-left: -2.5px; opacity: 1;">
</span>
<span class="atImgSpanSize">300 x 300</span>
</span>
</div>
```